# No internet, but local network works

Tags: networking, server, 20.04

For some reason every time I set up a new ubuntu server (for our build agents) I mange to mess it up and have some problem with network.

Note that this machine was set up 1 hour ago (then I tried to make the internet work, but failed...) and basically I just followed the setup process without doing anything special.

This time around I installed `20.04.02` and the internal network seems to work but there's no internet.
This means I can ping internal computers, I can ping the default gateway. I cannot ping `google.com` and I also cannot ping the ip-address which belongs to `google.com`.

IP4 set to DHCP.
IP6 disabled.

Some info:

```
ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 90:b1:1c:68:50:48 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.128.2.111/9 brd 10.255.255.255 scope global dynamic eno1
       valid_lft 690737sec preferred_lft 690737sec
    inet6 fe80::92b1:1cff:fe68:5048/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

```
ip r

10.128.0.0/9 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 10.128.2.111
172.16.0.0/12 via 10.128.0.1 dev eno1 proto dhcp src 10.128.2.111 metric 100
192.168.250.0/24 via 10.128.0.1 dev eno1 proto dhcp src 10.128.2.111 metric 100

ping 10.128.0.1
PING 10.128.0.1 (10.128.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.128.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.299 ms
```

```
cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
```

```
sudo cat /etc/network/interfaces
```

(file is empty)

```
ping google.com
ping: connect: Network is unreachable

# google.com ip
ping 172.217.168.14
ping: connect: Network is unreachable
```

Comment: It seems that the default gateway is not working properly. What kind of device is the gateway ? Router ?

Comment: I don't know what it is, some kind of router firewall. But note that this works fine on all other ubuntu servers in this network (it's from work).

Comment: Sorry its late here, might be that i am wrong but for me it seems that the default route is missing like: `default via 10.128.0.0 dev eno1` after that the ping to 172.217.168.14 should work. DNS depends on what is written / configured in `cat /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: and how can I add this default route? btw: In the meantime I tried adding a static ip (via the netplan yaml file) and it worked immediately...

Comment: For adding default route you can use command "ip route add default via <ip_adress_of_router>"